# Adafruit_LSM303 tilt compensated compass

Tags: accelerometer, magnetometer

I am having troubles with tilt compensating my compass.

I am using the LSM303DLHC accelerometer/compass in combination together with the Adafruit_LSM303_U.h.

I was able to get my compass to the right direction withthis little snippet:

```
  float heading = (atan2(event.magnetic.y,event.magnetic.x) * 180) / Pi;
```

I also was able to get my roll and tilt angle with converting my X and Y of my accelerometer to angles:

```
   headingNew = asin(eventA.acceleration.x/10);
   float tilt = headingNew*180/PI/90*100;
   headingNew = asin(eventA.acceleration.y/10);
   float roll = headingNew*180/PI/90*100;
```

Now I need to compensate my angle to get a new x and y for inside my heading calculation but the problem is that I can't seem to get the right functions.
Online I found the functions below from a large tutorial about the sensor but this gives me completely wrong values.

```
    //Xh = event.magnetic.x*cos(tilt)+event.magnetic.z*sin(tilt);
    //Yh = event.magnetic.x*sin(roll)*sin(tilt)+event.magnetic.y*cos(roll)-event.magnetic.z*sin(roll)*cos(tilt);
```

or in the code itself:

```
   Xh = event.magnetic.x*(eventA.acceleration.z/10)+event.magnetic.z*(eventA.acceleration.x/10);
   Yh = event.magnetic.x*(eventA.acceleration.y/10)*(eventA.acceleration.x/10)+event.magnetic.y*(eventA.acceleration.z/10)-event.magnetic.z*(eventA.acceleration.y/10)*(eventA.acceleration.z/10);
```

I actually get the right angle on a flat surface. But it is even more inaccurate at an angle as the normal heading.
Does anybody have any experience with this sensor? Already a big thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via this [Youtube movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHJEaB1iS30) I found a different [library](https://github.com/pololu/lsm303-arduino) and made this code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LSM303.h>
const int centreX  = 160;
const int centreY  = 120;
const int diameter = 100;
#define STMPE_CS 8
#define TFT_CS 10
#define TFT_DC 9

int last_dx, last_dy, dx, dy;
LSM303 compass;
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("meters Test"); Serial.println("");
Wire.begin();
compass.init();
compass.enableDefault();


compass.m_min = (LSM303::vector<int16_t>){-602, -704, -511}; //values from 
cailbration.
compass.m_max = (LSM303::vector<int16_t>){+557, +436, +529}; //values from 
cailbration.
last_dx = centreX;
last_dy = centreY;
}
void loop() {
compass.read();
double angle;
float heading = compass.heading();


angle= heading; //use heading from compass
dx = (diameter * cos((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreX;    // calculate X position
dy = (diameter * sin((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreY;    // calculate Y position
last_dx = dx;
last_dy = dy;
Serial.print("angle:"); Serial.println(angle);
Serial.println("tilt:"); Serial.println(compass.a.x);
delay(25);
}
```

Now everything works. Sometimes you just need to choose your battles.

Comment: can you explain those value const int centreX = 160;
const int centreY = 120;
const int diameter = 100;

Comment: Those values are to help the Unity application that takes in the data from the device over serial connection. For example when our installation gets turned I can just change these values instead of rebuilding the "desktop application"

Answer (score 3):

The `sin()` and `cos()` functions expect their arguments to be in
*radians*. If you feed them with anything else, be it degrees, percent
slope, or whatever, expect the result to be just crap.

---

**Edit**: The OP changed the question, invalidating my answer. So here
comes a new answer...

You have mistaken `eventA.acceleration.y` for `cos(tilt)`,
`eventA.acceleration.x` for `sin(tilt)`, and so on. *They are not the
same*. You may think they are the same up to some multiplicative factor,
and that's right. However, the factor doesn't cancel out as soon as you
do computations like `sin(roll)*sin(tilt)`. Don't rush your math: if you
want to transform known-good formulas to more practical ones, check every
step of the transformation carefully.

Comment: Actually for the sinus of the tilt I use my Accelerometer.x, for the cosinus of tilt the accelerometer.y.

Also for the sin of the roll I use the accelerometer.Y.


These are values from 0 to 1 that are the same as the cos/sin of a unit circle

Comment: @Roel: Re “_for the cosinus of tilt [I use] the accelerometer.y_”: I can't see that in the code you posted. If you are asking a question about a _different_ piece of code, then please edit the question and make sure the code you show is the one that matches your question.

Comment: I edited the question to show you how the code really looks like in my project.

Comment: I just want to know what Is wrong with the final function because I am not able to get the right result.

Comment: @Roel: **What's wrong**: it uses `eventA.acceleration.y` instead of `cos(tilt)`, etc. **Solution**: use the formula as published, with the angles in radians.

Comment: I changed it in my code and in the question. It didn't help me out. cos(tilt) = eventA.accel.z now. Didn't help me out

Comment: Reviewed everything. If you could check again.

I actually get the right angle on a flat surface. But it is even more inaccurate at an angle as the normal heading.